# Altering next_posts_link(); and previous_posts_link();

Tags: pagination

We use following two functions to display pagination.

```
<?php next_posts_link( 'Older Entries »'); ?>

<?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries »'); ?>
```

These above two function will output something like this

```
<a href="page link goes here">Older Entries »</a>
<a href="page link goes here">Newer Entries »</a>
```

Is there any way to add extra attribute with anchor link??

for e.g

```
<a href="page link goes here" class="name of the class" data-hover="Previous">Older</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I searched little and did this which is working.

```
add_filter('next_posts_link_attributes', 'posts_link_attributes_1');
add_filter('previous_posts_link_attributes', 'posts_link_attributes_2');

function posts_link_attributes_1() {
    return 'data-hover="Next" class="your class here"';
}
function posts_link_attributes_2() {
    return 'data-hover="Previous" class="your class here"';
}
```